# native html <select> not working on mobile view (Angular Page)

Tags: html, drop-down-menu

native `<select>` in html working well in desktop view. But in mobile view it's not drop down. Totally not working. The web page is working with angular. Also this drop down in a table..

```
<td >
  <select class="form-control" ng-model="month">
      <option value="Jan">January</option>
      <option value="Feb">Feb</option>
   </select>
</td>
```

someone can help me please... ? Thanks

Comment: have you tried using ng-options?

Comment: @Karim Yes buddy... not working.. :( ..